# iOS - More Options NSMenu in Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard, nsmenu

I need to implement a menu button where when you press it, a box of more options pops up underneath or over that button.

I've seen quite a few tutorials where people use .xib files to implement `NSMenu` objects, which are apparently only easily accessible when they're using xibs. I'm using just a storyboard, and can't seem to find it in the Object Library.

Is there a way to easily access and drag/drop an `NSMenu` in the Interface Builder when I'm only using a storyboard and not xibs files?

Comment: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/tags/menu

Comment: Wooow. I didn't know that directory of open source UI solutions existed! This is definitely gonna significantly ease my UI struggles. Thanks a ton! :D